# Adding Social Network Buttons to Events

Tags: social-media

How do you add a new social network button such as Instagram to a Event as part of its publication? Currently what is available is Twitter, FB and LinkedIn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What CMS are you using? Because it is not possible to add new social buttons. The reason for asking for the CMS is that you can create views in Drupal and so your own Event Page and then it is easy to add additional social buttions

Comment: Thanks, i am using Wordpress